# Handling newline character in input between Windows and Linux

Tags: java

I think this is a standard problem which may have been asked before but I could not get the exact answer so posting the issue.

The issue is that our server is running on a linux box. We access the server over the browser on a window box to enter data into field which is supposed to contain multiple lines which user can enter by pressing the enter key after each line
Abc
Def
GHI

When this input field (this is a text area),is read on the linux machine, we want to split the data based on new line character.

I had three question on this.

1. Does the incoming data contain "\r\n" or "\n"
2. If incoming data does contain "\r\n", the linux line.separator property (vm property) would not work for me as it would say "\n" and therefore may leave "\r" in the data.
3. If "\r" is left in the data, if I open the file on a windows machine, will this mean a newline character?

Finally can anyone tell me the standard way to deal with this issue?

Comment: I think this depends on what language you are using (is the "text area" in a Java app, HTML page, or something else?) and possibly what UI toolkit you are using.

Comment: We are using java based web application and its an html page. There is no other UI toolkit being used

Answer (score 3):

Linux uses `\n`.
Windows uses `\r\n`.

Therefore, unless you've tweaked something in linux, it should be coming in `\n`.

You could regex out `\r\n` and `\n` and replace with whatever you want to avoid problem 3.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: Yeah we are planning to do that, but it seems to me that this issue should have a more generic fix built in the language. As data being entered on windows and read on linux server is very common. May be I am overrating the language power but handling this in every application sounds very painful

Answer (score 3):

The standard `java.io.DataInputStream` and `java.io.BufferedInputReader` both handle this automatically through the readLine() method. You really should not use `DataInputStream` for this since it does not support character sets correctly and it's readLine() has been deprecated for a long time.

For text output, you can use `java.io.PrintWriter` in which it's printLn(), and related methods with parameters, output the correct newline sequence for the current platform. `java.io.BufferedWriter` also handles this correctly and provides a `public` newLine() method.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using regular expression, you can also make it simpler by doing something like.

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
// append your texts here and to go to a new line use
    if(System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")){

                sb.insert("\r\n");
            }
            else {
            sb.insert("\n");
    }
```

So if your local environment is windows , you can have this working locally and will also work if you're deploying to a different linux based environments.

Answer (score 0):

Probably try this?

```
String[] lines = inputString.split("\r?\n");
```

Not 100% sure about the syntax but the basic idea of the regex is: "zero or one \r, and exactly one \n". Or, if you just want to normalize the input:

```
inputString = inputString.replace("\r?\n", "\n");
```

Doesn't seem very painful to me. ;-)

Comment: I agree. this is not as painful. But I dont like basic idea of worrying about new line characters in application code when using a language like Java which has been there for enough years to give a better way to solve the problem :)... Though on the other hand its the way OS deals with newline differently the cause of concern which would probably never have a good consistent behavior for forseeable future

Comment: I couldn't agree more with you, but still, this is inter-OS, inter-network issue. HTTP mandates usage of "\r\n" to terminate lines, yet all *nix systems use "\n" internally. Or, Windows uses little-endian encoding of integers/pointers, but the network protocols require big-endianness of transmitted data. The truth is still out there somewhere. ;) And while we work with such inter-connected and different systems, we have to handle their quirks, unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the response guys.. Finally looking at suggestion given by Kevin, we used StringReader and BufferedReader wrapper over it to overcome the issue. We used string reader as data is read as a  string from the request.

Hopefully this question helps people in future

Comment: Please don't post answers to your own questions when you have nothing to add. That's what comments are for...